# How is the keyword “this” interpreted inside a computed property name?

Tags: javascript

Consider the two following examples.

```
var obj1 = {
    "a": "A",
    "b": "B",
    [this.a + this.b]: function(a) {return a + this.a}
};

console.log(obj1.AB("a"))
//TypeError: obj1.AB is not a function  

var obj2 = {
    "a": "A",
    "b": "B",
    "AB": function(a) {return a + this.a}
};  

console.log(obj2.AB("a"))
//aA
```

What is the reason of Error in the first example? How is the keyword “this” interpreted if it occurs inside a computed property name?

Comment: An object doesn't have its own context

Comment: Why does `this.a` refer to `obj2.a` on the right side, but doesn't work on the left side?

Comment: @Kaiido: can you please explain? Where should I define `self.a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [Computed Property Names](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

You can see that you can put an expression inside bracket which may leads to the following construct
`[(console.log(x),x)]` which returns `x` but allows us to dump what it holds before.

```js
const a = {
  [(console.log('log:', this.a + this.b), this.a + this.b)]: 'test'
}
// this.a is undefined and summing them is NaN
console.log(a.NaN) // 'test'
```

If we now consider below

```js
;(function () {
  const a = {
    [(console.log('log', this.a + this.b), this.a + this.b)]: 'top'
  }
  console.log(a.zz) // 'top'
}).call({ a: 'z', b: 'z' })
```

we do get some zztop.

I have not read all the spec but to some extent we may rely on [the running execution context's](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-getthisenvironment) to determine `this`

- In the first case: the global environnement
- In the later: function which has been bound with `{a: 'z', b: 'z'}`

Because we are a bit greedy:

```js
window.a = 'z'
window.b = 'z'
const c = {
  [(console.log('log', this.a + this.b), this.a + this.b)]: 'test'
}
console.log(c.zz) // 'test'
```

---

edit: regarding the `this` in the function. It is **not** linked to the `this` of the expression used to compute the property name and lives its life

```js
const a = {
  hello: 'top',
  zz: function () { console.log(this.hello) } // top
}
a.zz()
// the first this is resolved as the global env
// the this in function is resolved as b
const b = {
  hello: 'top',
  [(console.log('the this.hello is undef', this.hello), 'zz')]: function () { console.log(this.hello) } // top. The caller is b.
}
b.zz()
// and some usual invocation where this is bound to a
const c = {
  hello: true,
  ['zz']: function () { console.log(this.hello) } // top
}
a.hello = 'TOP'
c.zz.call(a) // TOP
```

Comment: But what does `this.a` refer to if it occurs on the right side? My second example seems to show that `this.a` refers to `obj2.a`...

Comment: oops did not focus on the function part because was less curious. In the right side, the running context is obj2 because you invoked obj2.AB()
if e.g you run ```obj2.AB.call({ a: 'z'})``` you would get 'zz' @lyricallywicked

Comment: Is there any way to refer to `obj1` inside the left side (the computed property name) of one of its elements?

Comment: The way you construct it, not that I know of because obj1 is not yet defined.
should you have ```ob1 = {a:'A', b: 'B'}; obj1[[obj1.a + obj1.b]] = '2'``` then yes (```obj1.AB==2```)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, we should not create a property of JS object like this:

```
[this.a + this.b]: function(a) {return a + this.a}.
```

The left hand side has to be a calling name. On the other hand, the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding). It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called. In second example:

```
"AB": function(a) {return a + this.a}
```

here you have called return a (this would be the argument passed to the function) + this.a. Here this refers to the obj2 and the value of its property "a".

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign key like this way
No if you check below your code you can see you function key is NaN
you are trying to add two undefined keys that is why it shows `NaN`
please keep in mind its `Object` not `constructor`

```js
var obj1 = {
    "a": "A",
    "b": "B",
    [this.a + this.b]: function(a) { return a + this.a }
};

console.log(obj1);
```

Now to solve you problem you can
First create Object and add foo

```js
var obj1 = {
    a: "A",
    b: "B",
};
obj1[obj1.a + obj1.b] = function(a) { return a + this.a };
console.log(obj1.AB("a"));
```